# How to update only A particular field(other fields should remain same) in access Database with c# form App

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access

I Am working on A form app in c# 
in which there is An table where i was updating same data regularly
in my db there is a table named customers has following columns

CustomerId | Balance   |   Last_Bill_Id   |   Last_Bill_Date  |  Last_Bill_Total   |   Last_Deposited   |   Last_Deposited_Date    |

right now i'm using this 
code to update my db

```
 try
        {

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = G:\\my Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\xml_and_db_test\\xml_and_db_test\\bin\\Debug\\database_for_kissan_Pashu_AhaR_Bills.mdb");
         string queryText = "UPDATE Customers SET Balance = ? ,Last_Bill_Id = ?,Last_Bill_Date = ? ,Last_Bill_Total = ?,Last_Deposited = ? , Last_Deposited_Date =?  where CustomerId = ?;";


            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryText, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;







            cmd.Parameters.Add("Balance", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Last_Bill_Id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 15;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Last_Bill_Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Last_Bill_Total", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 1560;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Last_Deposited", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 500;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Last_Deposited_Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;



            cmd.Parameters.Add("CustomerId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);





            con.Open(); // open the connection
            //OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            int yy = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            textBox3.Text = "update Done";
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string c = ex.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(c);

        }
```

**Problem**
Some time i don't wants to update **Last_Deposited  And Last_Deposited_Date**  fields then 
i have tried this code

```
  try
        {

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = G:\\my Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\xml_and_db_test\\xml_and_db_test\\bin\\Debug\\database_for_kissan_Pashu_AhaR_Bills.mdb");


            string queryText = "UPDATE Customers SET Balance = ? ,Last_Bill_Id = ?,Last_Bill_Date = ? ,Last_Bill_Total = ?  where CustomerId = ?;";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryText, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;







            cmd.Parameters.Add("Balance", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Last_Bill_Id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 15;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Last_Bill_Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Last_Bill_Total", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 1560;

        //    cmd.Parameters.Add("Last_Deposited", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 500;

       //     cmd.Parameters.Add("Last_Deposited_Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;



            cmd.Parameters.Add("CustomerId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);





            con.Open(); // open the connection
            //OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            int yy = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            textBox3.Text = "update Done";
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string c = ex.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(c);

        }
```

now whenever i'm updating my dB with second code the values saved in Last_Deposited And Last_Deposited_Date  are being deleted i don't wants to remove these values only wants to update when new values are available for these fields.

Comment: Just remove those fields from your query text.

Comment: How is it "not working"? If you don't update those fields in your query they won't get changed - unless you have a trigger on the table, which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: I don't know why It't not working here is query Am using    string queryText = "UPDATE Customers SET Balance = ? ,Last_Bill_Id = ?,Last_Bill_Date = ? ,Last_Bill_Total = ?  where CustomerId = ?;";     it's updating All fields mentioned but removing previous data from Last_Deposited And Last_Deposited_Date

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to update your 2 fields you can just don't assign them in your update query.

Comment: @TasleemAhmad your second update should not update Last_Deposited And Last_Deposited_Date fields

Comment: string queryText = "UPDATE Customers SET Balance = ? ,Last_Bill_Id = ?,Last_Bill_Date = ? ,Last_Bill_Total = ?  where CustomerId = ?;";

Comment: I'm not updating you can see it's updating all other value but removing previous values in Last_Deposited And Last_Deposited_Date

Comment: Try this query UPDATE Customers SET Balance = ? ,Last_Bill_Id = ?,Last_Bill_Date = ? ,Last_Bill_Total = ?,Last_Deposited = Last_Deposited,Last_Deposited_Date=Last_Deposited_Date  where CustomerId = ?

Comment: getting the same result It's clearing previously save data from  Last_Deposited And Last_Deposited_Date     :(